# Extending Native JavaScript Objects

Tags: javascript

I am using [Salt.JS](https://github.com/james2doyle/saltjs) to create a micro-library (sort of like JQuery) for a project. The great thing about Salt.JS is that I can use JQuery like syntax e.g. `$('#my_element_id')`.

I am having a bit of a challenge with making some native extensions. I have the following code:

```
window.Element.prototype.on = function(eventType, callback) {
    //code here
};

window.NodeList.prototype.on = function(eventType, callback) {
    //code here
};

window.HTMLCollection.prototype.on = function(eventType, callback) {
    //code here
};
```

which allows me to attach events to Elements, NodeLists, and HTMLCollections like so:

```
$('#my-element-id').on('click', callback);
$('.all-my-divs').on('click', callback);
```

However, now I want to attach an `on` event to `window` e.g. to enable things like a resize callback. I want to able to do something like this:

```
var resized = function(){
    console.log('ALWAYS BE RESIZING!');
};
var el_win = $('window');    //I've updated Salt.JS to return window object 
el_win.on('resize', resized);
```

What native extension can I make to my existing code to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

> What native extension can I make to my existing code to enable this?

You could just alias *addEventListener* as *on*

```
if (!('on' in Window.prototype)) // don't shadow if it exists
    Object.defineProperty(Window.prototype, 'on', {
        value: Window.prototype.addEventListener,
        configurable: true // let other things make changes to this too
    });

// now, e.g.
window.on('click', console.dir.bind(console)); // works the same as addEventListener
```

Many people don't like extending the *DOM* though, so you may also want to consider writing a wrapper for *DOM nodes* that you can extend safely.

Here is an example of how you might achieve such a wrapper for a generic node

```
function wrap(node) {
    var o = {node: node}, i,
        map = [
            {alias: 'on', native: 'addEventListener'},
            {alias: 'off', native: 'removeEventListener'}
        ];
    if (node && node.constructor && node.constructor.prototype)
        for (i = 0; i < map.length; ++i)
            if (map[i].native in node.constructor.prototype)
                o[map[i].alias] = node.constructor.prototype[map[i].native].bind(node);
    return o;
}

// now, e.g.
wrap(window).on('click', console.dir.bind(console));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I appreciate that extending the DOM has its issues. I'm open to any approach that won't kill past or future code. However, I'm not an expert on these kind of structural matters.